# Is there a twitter post method in an iframe for mobile safari?

Tags: javascript, iframe, twitter, src

I have the following iframe embedded in a div.

```
<div id="sharepopup" class="sharepopup">
    <iframe id="social" class="social" frameborder="0">
    </iframe>
    <div id="shareclosebutton" class="shareclose"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS for the iframe is...

```
    iframe.social{
    background:#ffffff;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -ms-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:10px;
    width:480px;
    height:180px;
    z-index:102;
    }
```

And I am trying to do this...

```
document.getElementById('social').src="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=&text=Check%20out%20this%20page&tw_p=tweetbutton&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.MYSITE.co.uk%2Fhhg%2FMYPAGE.html?="+pagenumber;
```

when I make the container div visible
but all I get is a blank iframe.

Has anyone else managed to get the web content working in an iframe?
No JQUERY answers please.

Comment: you can use ajax post or send a get request to a server

Comment: @raam86 Do you have an example of this? It would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `$.post(YOUR_URL_TO_GET_PATH,function(data){console.log(data)//do stuff})`

Comment: a jsfiddle or demo page? I'm sorry, the single line of code is as obscure as anything i've read on dev.twitter.com.

Comment: just replace the `YOUR_URL_TO_GET_PATH` with the actual path your are  trying to post to. You execute it from the browser console or curl or whatever

Comment: Please provide a page with a working example. Fiddling with that line of code produced nothing that worked... Thanks.